# JQuery accordion content right border doesn't show

Tags: jquery, css, border

I am using JQuery's accordion. I want a border around the content panel, so I have the following in my CSS file:

```
.ui-accordion-content {
    border:1px solid; 
    border-color:#9db0bf;
}
```

It works but doesn't draw the right border (I already tried Chrome, Firefox and IE, it's not a browser problem). This is the result:
[image: result with missing border]

Comment: Perhaps the box is going outside of an element with `overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my mistake
I have forgotten the following somewhere in my CSS file, just found it:

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    border-right: 3px;
}
```

I deleted it and it works.

Answer (score 3):

May be border is not visible because it's going outside of container. Reduce the width by 2px and check.

Answer (score 2):

give padding in ui-accordion-content css class. You will see border.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `margin:1px;` around the box to avoid it to escape out from its parent that might have `overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 1):

Check width in following css

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content
```